# Solve for the power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-process

I have two vectors $S_{t=0}$ and $S_{t=n}$. They are related by the following equation:

$S_{t=n} = S_{t=0}\,T^{N}$

where $T$ is a transition matrix and $N$ is an integer.

How do I solve this equation for $N$?

Comment: Is $T$ diagonalizable i.e. can you write it in the form $T=UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: It is possible to diagonalize $T$. However, not all of the eigenvalues are real. $T$ is a square matrix though

Comment: If you know that $T$ has eigenvectors $e_i$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ then write $S(0)=\sum a_i e_i$ and $S(n)=\sum b_i e_i$. You then have $a_i=b_i \lambda_i^n$ which should be easy to solve for $n$.

Comment: What are $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, sorry? The eigenvalues for vectors $S(0)$ and $S(n)$, respectively?